# Is there an equivalent to IOHelper::ensureFolderExists in Craft 3?

Tags: plugin-development, migration

Migrating Plugins to Craft 3 starts bugging me, seems that really everything changed.
Is there an equivalent to `IOHelper::ensureFolderExists` in Craft 3?

Answer (score 3):

In Craft 3, the `IOHelper` class has been replaced by the [`FileHelper`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-helpers-filehelper.html) class.

The closest Craft 3 equivalent to `IOHelper::ensureFolderExists()` is

```
FileHelper::createDirectory($path);
```